# How to rename a file name named "."

Tags: linux, file-rename

I have downloaded a large file about 2gigs from remote server but by mistake I gave it name . (dot).

How can I rename it using linux commands ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23512020/1030675

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really have named it `.`. Or at least, you cannot have done so successfully.

The name `.` is reserved for the current directory. So either it has been given another name implicitly, or it has been removed/discarded.

Try

```
find -size +1536M -ls
```

to find if there is any file with this size, and if so, verify if it can be the file you look for.

Comment: Now as I think about it, it is probably named `. ` (dot space) or something alike. In this case, you should fond out the exact name and then do `mv '. ' myfile -iv`.