# Renaming a '.' file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I downloaded a file using rsync and accidentaly provided it the destination as '.' (I thought it is the directory to download into). So it downloaded the multi-gig file but named it '.'.

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 root   apache       4096 May  7 00:42 .
drwxr-sr-x 7 me apache       4096 May  7 00:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1   1006   1006 2008805206 Apr  5 04:49 .
-rw------- 1 root   apache       1675 May  7 00:25 somefile
-rw------- 1 root   apache        392 May  7 00:26 anotherfile.txt
```

How do I rename the 2GB+ '.' file to something meaningful. Nothing I do seems to work (i've tried mv, rename, etc.) but they all say

```
Device or resource busy
```

Comment: better suited over att superuser or similar, but one way is to use the inode-number, get it using `ls -i` or `stat` then you can move/rename it using `find -inode -exec mv...`

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It is more appropriate on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: LOL can you write the exact command? How did you manage to do it?

Comment: it was ```rsync -avzP -e "ssh -i /path/to/pub/key" username@server.com:folder/file.ext .```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23512004/1030675

Answer (score 1):

You can use this mv:

```
mv ./.[[:blank:]]* myfile
```

Or else try this find:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '. *' -exec mv '{}' myfile \;
```

Comment: says: ```mv: target `myfile' is not a directory```
and for the second one executes fine but doesn't rename. I had to remove ```-maxdepth 1``` (there wasn't much in the directory anyway)

Comment: Can you tell me output of: `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -exec printf "<%s>\n" '{}' \;` command

Comment: Your posted answer will move every file in that directory not just this one

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a superuser question. But I found a solution elsewhere, so thanks everyone for trying. We could do this using:

`find . -type f | (let i=0; while read f; do mv "$f" "$f"-$i ; let i=$i+1; done)`

Not the most elegant way and probably very insecure too (as there is no undo).

Answer (score -1):

Type this from the directory where it is located.

```
mv ./. newfile
```

Comment: Tried. Does not work.